# Gradient color filter in Java

Tags: java, javascript, filter, gradient

I am trying to write a method in a pic filter program that will change a picture to a pallet of gradient colors.  amountRed and amountGreen are supposed to increase by 1 in each pixel as the program runs, and amountBlue is supposed to stay constant at 126.  Here is what I have:

```
public static void gradient(Picture target) {
    int amountBlue = 126;

    for(int x=0; x < target.width(); x++){
        for(int y=0; y < target.height(); y++){
            target.set(x, y, new Color(x, y, amountBlue));
        }
    }       
}
```

It is currently giving me an all black output and a parameter error, I believe I need to divide by width and height somewhere.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the part of JavaScript ? or just related because of name !

Comment: There's a GradientPaint class you can use to paint gradients.

Comment: I need to do it in this way, using a simple method to iterate through pixels and add RGB to each.  It adds 1 R with each increase in x, and 1 G with each increase in y